# What are the disadvantages that I can use to punish characters exclusively relying on darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light

As a player, I had a history of being bullied for playing a human and being the only one that didn't pick a race that had darkvision. Example quote that illustrates my experiences as a player:

> tl;dr pick something with darkvision i.e. probably not human because we don't want to carry torches because we metagame stealth and the GM not only allows but also encourages this

As a GM and GM assistant, I want to use official rules to punish and possibly invalidate the idea of relying on darkvision and not using a light source because I have a personal grudge against the idea of darkvision without a light source. I would like to force them to bring a light source with them despite their darkvision.

Therefore, I want to know:

**What are the disadvantages to relying solely on darkvision?**

Comment: This needs a system tag. Further, while I sympathize with your frustration, other readers may not be as generous. Posing this question in a more neutral fashion will likely see it better received—something like *What are the disadvantages to relying exclusively on darkvision?*

Comment: I agree with i can chan. A lot of people on this exchange have a bad history with DM's who punish their character due to a personal grudge(Me being one of them) so a question asking how you can punish your players due to a personal grudge will not be well received.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think that stuff should be left in. It seems that punishing characters is a major motivation and context for OP's request and that should be addressed by answers. It might affect the reception of this question, but leaving that content in will enable answers to fully address OP's issue I think.

Comment: torches, lanterns and races like human that don't have darkvision

Comment: @Rubiksmoose While I agree that all of the question's information allows answers to provide a completer treatment of the asker's issues, I also think the site owes new users an explanation as to why their questions might not be well-received. (Honestly, I'd rather this question be about mechanics and the other issues be offered up in a separate question like *Is this a reasonable and healthy reaction to these events?* or something.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I definitely agree that explaining is the correct course of action and that can be accomplished by answers and comments. I don't see that removing the context of the question is going to help OP at all. While it could work as two questions, I've certainly seen very good responses to similarly phrased questions in the past and I don't think it'll be an issue. That being said, that's all just how I'm seeing it. If others feel strongly about it, feel free to edit it. (The idea of doing it this way seemed to have support of a few members in chat when I ran it by them fwiw)

Comment: @UmbrieShadowsong Do you perhaps mean "discourage" instead of "punish"? Although a personal grudge *could* be a reason for asking this question, I don't think it should be because the Q is interesting/relevant enough by itself (and also because grudges usually don't work well on the long term in social interactions).

Answer (score 8):

To start off, I'm sorry you had this experience. There are better tables and better people at them than what you've shared here. With that out of the way,

### The downsides to relying solely on darkvision to deal with dark areas are fourfold:

1. First, there are always opportunity costs involved. Whatever you're spending to get darkvision (racial or class choices, magic items, feats, anything), you're giving something else up to get it. Being a human, halfling, or dragonborn might suit your build better than something with darkvision would.
2. Second, darkvision itself has its limits: you're completely blind beyond 60 feet, granting advantage to ranged attacks made against you from outside that radius. You're making Perception checks at disadvantage just to see anything within that radius, and even if you can, you won't be able to make out colors.
3. Third, even though these downsides come with upsides that the party can leverage through composition and strategy (especially if the DM doesn't leverage the downsides), it still confines the party to a more restricted range of capabilities.
4. The fourth and final downside is for the players, not the characters: it requires buy-in from the entire table, as any variation from the strategy will either hamper the other players by eliminating the darkness they were relying on, or is likely to annoy them if they're not amenable to the night-blind character not pulling their weight. And you've seen and shared with us how this can lead to hurt feelings.

### So, what can you, as a DM who doesn't want darkvision to be viable in your game, do to enforce it?

No matter what route you take, you're going to have to be open with your players about this. You don't need to be open to argument and discussion about whether you're going to do it; you just need to be open, from the beginning, that it is something you will be doing. If you keep quiet and try to spring it on them after they've made their choices, **you will not be their DM for long**, because your players will either leave for better tables or resent you.

The easy solution is to simply ban darkvision. Whether you ban it line-item (elves no longer have darkvision, goggles of night don't confer it) or ban the whole package (elves are not playable, goggles of night no longer exist) is up to you, though in the former case you may end up unbalancing the races/classes/feats/etc involved. Again, do this before, not after, your players make their decisions. Don't spring it on them.

The more difficult (but in the long run, more rewarding) solution is to leverage the downsides as stated prior. Send them up occasionally against situations that play to their weaknesses. Examples include enemies throwing light on them (or just having better darkvision, like drow) so that they can attack the party from outside darkvision range, or situations where color is important but light will bring trouble, or an enemy where getting the drop on them in the darkness is either impossible (maybe it has blindsight or tremorsense?) or ineffective. **If you're coming to the table with the grudge you describe, I wouldn't recommend even trying this**, because if you're not keeping the players' fun in mind and respecting their choices, it can easily be overdone and tip over into invalidating their choices. And you remember how that feels.

Realistically, though, be prepared to have to choose between keeping either players at the table or darkvision out of your game.

Answer (score 3):

There are some simple choices:

1. Have all your adventures be in well lit places/ignore lighting
   conditions in game-play. Not so much a punishment, but since, as
   sevenbrokenbricks mentions in his answer, darkvision always comes
   with an opportunity cost, this does somewhat weaken any character
   concept that selects it as it becomes a useless ability.
2. Umbral Sight. From Xanathar's Guide, the Gloom Stalker Ranger archetype has
   an ability called Umbral Sight, which not only grants them
   darkvision (or extends existing darkvision), but also makes them
   invisible against creatures relying on darkvision. The only way to
   see the ranger, then, is to have a light source or some other form
   of vision, such as blind sight or tremor sense. Which brings us to...
3. Tremorsense, blindsight, darkvision, life sense, etc. If all of your
   opponents have vision types that eliminate the darkness penalty (or
   at least reduce it at least as much as darkvision), then darkvision
   doesn't provide a tactical advantage. However, if anything, this
   may make darkvision more of a necessity in order to keep up with
   enemies. Of course, if all your enemies have darkvision, the PCs
   without it could then deploy the same countermeasures mentioned here
   without spoiling with your darkvision capable PC's advantage
   (since they no longer have one).
4. Fairy Fire. And other spells that create light. Basically, have all of your encounters light up your PCs with a
   spell that makes them visible well beyond the range of darkvision so
   that the enemies can range them, or that otherwise makes darkvision
   meaningless. For bonus points, use light to mislead. Damcing lights (a cantrip) has a range of 120 feet. Have it move 10' ahead of the enemy, acting as a decoy. Your enemy can see the area illuminated by the dancing lights (the radius ends at their feet so they can see where they are stepping) but since the light doesn't illuminate them, they don't necessarily give away their position. The spell creates multiple lights, so the other lights could range further ahead, exposing the PCs long before the enemy force is within the range of darkvision. Other light based spells could probably be utilized to similar effect. Be creative.
5. Give it to everyone. Darkvision is fairly easy to come by in 5E - if you don't get it as a racial option, many classes offer it and it is a second level spell that lasts 8 hours. It also occurs on a fair selection of low-level magic items. In addition to this, of you decide, you could simply make darkvision potions cheap (25 gold for 8 hours), or make a common magic item that permanently provides it (for 100 or 200 gold) easily available in most cities.
6. Sunlight Sensitivity. Drow suffer from sunlight sensitivity, gaining disadvantage to perception and attack rolls if they or their target are in direct sunlight. Expand this to apply to all darkvision. Not rules legal, but an option per DM fiat.

My personal advice (which you didn't ask for, so consider this a bonus or off-topic as you prefer) is that such pettiness is going to lead to problems sooner rather than later. Each of these suggestions are a good tactic for shutting down an opponent's advantage from darkvision and should be used (with the possible exception of 5 and definite exception of 6) to varying degree, but these tactics are available to players as well as enemies. Non-darkvision characters should be encouraged to use them. However, characters (and bad guys) should also be allowed to play to their strengths, and act to compensate for their weaknesses. Allow characters that have chosen darkvision to shine by getting the jump on some non-darkvision enemies (or spoil an ambush) every now and again. But don't make the whole adventure cater to darkvision (or to foiling it).

One of the important things to remember is that even the Underdark isn't all dark. Dark elf cities are well lit, just like a human settlement. Many of the lichen and fungi that grow there are bio-luminescent. Darkvision has limits - it only works to a limited range (usually 60'), it still only makes darkness function as dim light (incurring disadvantage on visual tasks), and you can't see colors. So even creatures with darkvision often seek or carry light sources so that they can see better. This means that a torch isn't that out of place and that those without torches aren't completely helpless.

So while darkvision is useful, it isn't a must have feature. If you play it right, those with it won't really have the footing to stand on to criticize a player for not taking it. If your previous DMs have been over valuing it or not acknowledging its limitations, then you end up in the situation you describe. Most competent [valuations of the 5E races](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?501272-Detect-Balance-an-Improved-Scale-for-Measuring-5e-Races) rate variant human among the best, even without darkvision, so those players and DMs you have dealt with that look at you funny (or worse) for not taking it are considered by the larger community to be flatly wrong.